# O(n) algorithm to find primes up to n

Tags: algorithms, discrete-mathematics, primes

I don't know the name of this algorithm, but anyway it was interesting to share (btw Linear sieve, Sieve of Atkin and Sieve of Pritchard performs better)

The main idea is to use the Fundamental theorem of arithmetic, and iterate through primes and at each prime cancel out every possible number expressed as a product of the current prime and only primes <= the current prime with recursion. An observation is that at each main step, you can reach with consistency the next prime

Informal proof of why is O(n):
There are in the loop at most O(n) call to function f starting with different primes, then for every function f it make recursive calls going in the prime list backwards (and only backwards), multiplying along the way the primes, in this way it reach every non prime number exactly once due to Fundamental theorem of arithmetic.
Notice that in the loop within f, it stops also when it exceed the limit n, and so multiplying others primes greater than the current one will always exceed this limit

```
func PrimesUpTo(n int) []bool {
    isPrime := make([]bool, n+1)
    for i := 2; i <= n; i++ {
        isPrime[i] = true
    }
    primes := make([]int, 0)
    var f func(int, int)
    f = func(i int, prod int) {
        for j := 0; j <= i && primes[j]*prod <= n; j++ {
            isPrime[primes[j]*prod] = false
            f(j, primes[j]*prod)
        }
    }
    lastIndex := 0
    for i := 2; i < n; i++ {
        if isPrime[i] {
            primes = append(primes, i)
            f(lastIndex, i)
            lastIndex++
        }
    }
    return isPrime
}
```

Possible optimizations could be:

- At the beginning remove manually all multiples of 2 (except 2) (example: https://github.com/lorenzotinfena/goji/blob/main/math/primes.go)
- Using a bitset to store "isPrime"
- Compute in O(1) a strict upper bound of max size of "primes"

Comment: See: Melissa O'Neill, "The Genuine Sieve of Eratosthenes". https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf

Comment: Please argue $O(n)$.

Comment: @greybeard I added a little explanation

Comment: I'm unable to verify whether your algorithm runs in O(n) and produces the correct answer, but I can confirm that the simple linear sieve algorithm indeed runs in O(n) and produces the correct answer.